# Plotting multiple pie charts in a single figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

these are my columns:

```
SeniorCitizen  Partner   Dependent
Yes            Yes       No  
No             Yes       No 
No             No        Yes
Yes            No        No
```

I wanted to plot separate pie charts of all these columns in a single figure or sheet. This is my code:

```
ax1 = df2['SeniorCitizen'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), fontsize=10, 
                                              labels = ['No', 'Yes'], autopct='%1.0f%%')
ax1.set_title('% of Senior Citizens', fontsize = 12)
plt.show()

ax2 = df2['Partner'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), fontsize=10, autopct='%1.0f%%')
ax2.set_title('% of People with and without partner', fontsize = 12)
plt.show()

ax2 = df2['Dependents'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), fontsize=10, autopct='%1.0f%%')
ax2.set_title('% of People with and without dependent', fontsize = 12)
plt.show()
```

The output comes in a straight line one after the other. I think there is this concept called subplots to make it appear in like horizontal form.

Can anyone help with explanation and code?
Something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# If you want a 2 by 2 grid of plots, do:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)

# "axes" will be a list of all the matplotlib.axes.Axes objects

# For one 4-long row of plots:
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4)

# And one 4-tall column:
fig, axes = plt.subplot(4, 1)

# etc
```

Your code can be adapted to:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3)

axes[0].plot(df2['SeniorCitizen'].value_counts(), kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), fontsize=10, 
                                              labels = ['No', 'Yes'], autopct='%1.0f%%')
axes[0].set_title('% of Senior Citizens', fontsize = 12)

axes[1].plot(df2['Partner'].value_counts(), kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), fontsize=10, autopct='%1.0f%%')
axes[1].set_title('% of People with and without partner', fontsize = 12)

axes[2].plot(df2['Dependents'].value_counts(), kind='pie', figsize=(5,5), fontsize=10, autopct='%1.0f%%')
axes[2].set_title('% of People with and without dependent', fontsize = 12)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks. but its only showing one chart with values clubbed together...It should appear something like the picture..

Comment: @OmanBilal I have edited my code to call the `plot` method of the `Axes` objects, does it work now?

Comment: Error: 'Line2D' object has no property 'kind'...I believe ax.plot won't work with this. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to pass e.g., `ax=axes[2]` to the dataframe's plot method